# plutus example of interacting with wallet on testnet using haskell

Tags: wallet, haskell, testnet

Can anyone proivde an example of how to create a wallet that can be used in the Main.hs file when connected to the testnet?   I have working code for Emulator and Simulator, but all examples against testnet are done via the REST API call to invoke a a contract instance with a wallet.   Here is the code fragment that I need to work for testnet, and I know the wallet ID in advance, but I don't know how to create a Wallet instance that can replace the defaultWallet below.

Simulator code:

main :: IO ()
main = void $ Simulator.runSimulationWith handlers $ do
Simulator.logString @(Builtin StarterContracts) "Starting plutus-starter PAB webserver on port 8080. Press enter to exit."
shutdown <- PAB.Server.startServerDebug

```
cidInit <- Simulator.activateContract defaultWallet InitContract
adminPkh <- Simulator.handleAgentThread defaultWallet ownPubKeyHash
```

...
Run code:
main :: IO ()
main = do
runWith (Builtin.handleBuiltin @StarterContracts)
shutdown <- PAB.Server.startServerDebug

```
cidInit <- Core.activateContract (Wallet ???) InitContract
adminPkh <- Core.handleAgentThread (Wallet ???)  ownPubKeyHash
```